# WPF DataGrid Row Coloring

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, visual-studio-2015, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid where rows MAY have a status that has a color code or data that requires them to be bolded.  I have been able to easily get the bolding to work.  If it does have a color code, I want the entire row background to be displayed in that color.  I have scoured several sites and tried many different ways to get the row color coded, but none of them seem to work.  What am I missing?

**Datagrid.xaml (style):**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Foreground="Red"
                               Text="!" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#AAFFFF" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#AAFFD4" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal_AlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#E6F7FF" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#2e90d1" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#2980b9" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFE6" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFF80" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                    ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                                      SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen,
                                                                                                                     ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
                                                                                                                     Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter},
                                                                                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                               SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                               Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility,
                                                                    ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row},
                                                                    Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter},
                                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Regular" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**ListManager.xaml (form):**

```
<DataGrid 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLead, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding LeadListFiltered}" 
                              x:Name="grdWorkLeadList"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              Margin="-10,8,2,0"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              AlternationCount="2"
                        SelectionChanged="grdWorkLeadList_SelectionChanged"
                        LoadingRow="grdWorkLeadList_LoadingRow">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Campaign" Binding="{Binding SetupCampaign.Name}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Action Status" Binding="{Binding ActionStatus}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Action Date" Binding="{Binding ActionDate,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" SortMemberPath="Lastname">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Title }" />
                                            <Run Text=" " />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Firstname }" />
                                            <Run Text=" " />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Lastname }" />
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding Product  }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sailing" Binding="{Binding Sailing,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stateroom" Binding="{Binding Stateroom  }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Booking Date" Binding="{Binding BookingDate,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cancel Date" Binding="{Binding CancelDate,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}"  />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disposition" Binding="{Binding DispositionValue}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Booking" Binding="{Binding Booking  }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Run Date" Binding="{Binding RunDate ,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Phone  }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Followup" Binding="{Binding ActionFollowup}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID    }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assigned Agent" Binding="{Binding AssignedAgent }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding ActiveStatus  }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disposition Date" Binding="{Binding DispositionDate ,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rebook #" Binding="{Binding ReBookNumber    }" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Close Date" Binding="{Binding CloseDate ,StringFormat=\{0:MM dd yyyy\}}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason" Binding="{Binding ReasonDescription}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code    }" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

**Code-behind (cs):**

```
private void grdWorkLeadList_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Lead item = e.Row.Item as Lead;

    string color;
    if (item != null)
    {
        //handle status colors
        if (item.CurrentDisposition != null)
            using (var db = new DAOutboundCM_DEVEntities())
            {
                color = (from d in db.SetupDispositionLists where d.ID == item.CurrentDisposition select d.Color).Single();
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color));
                e.Row.UpdateLayout();

            }

        //handle priority bolding
        if (item.SetupCampaign.Name.Contains("Quotes"))
            if (item.Phone != null && item.Phone != "")
                e.Row.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted too much code, that may confuse the one who want to answer your question. 
Please try to explain briefly about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF it's good practice to only set a property once, otherwise you can get unexpected behavior. My guess why the bolding works and the coloring doesn't is because although you've set both in code behind, you've set the Background color in the Style also.

Does the issue remain when you remove the setter in your Style?

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
```

**EDIT**

Looks like you're unable to assign Background colors in code behind, because you haven't implemented the Background property in your template.

```
prop="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Digging a little deeper it turns out you're also setting the background three times in your code.

1. The dummy line you allready removed
2. In code behind when loading the rows
3. The row background through templated VisualStates

To see if your code behind works, you can

replace

```
<Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#AAFFFF" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#AAFFD4" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
```

with

```
<Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

and comment out your

```
<!--<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    ...
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>-->
```

in your DataGridRow ControlTemplate.

Comment: @KathrynSimmons Updated my answer.

Comment: Worked as soon as I took it out!  Thanks!